# What is the difference between ObjectClass=user and (&(sAMAccountType=805306368)(sAMAccountName=userName))?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Retrieve all the groups of a specific user in Active directory. May I use which one is the efficient filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the server version your AD environment is running on, it won't make a bit of difference.

Take a look at the documentation for [`objectClass`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-objectclass), [`sAMAccountName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-samaccountname) and [`sAMAccountType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-samaccounttype). You will notice that one property it lists on those pages is "Is Indexed". That tells you if that attribute is indexed in each server version. `sAMAccountName` and `sAMAccountType` have always been indexed, and `objectClass` started being indexed in Windows Server 2008.

If you're trying to find a specific account, you only need the `sAMAccountName` in the query:

```
(sAMAccountName=userName)
```

That will perform very fast, since `sAMAccountName` is indexed. The only reason you might want to include `sAMAccountType` or `objectClass` is if you don't know the type of object it is, and you want to make sure you only get a user account.

You mention you want to retrieve all the groups for a user, so take a look at the article I wrote about that: [Finding all of a user’s groups](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/06/08/finding-all-of-a-users-groups.html). The code examples are C#, but the principles apply to any language.

Comment: really I can get some clarification on from your answer, but I have some query on this you said if I use  (sAMAccountName=userName) this may I get an only user account. Here may I know user account contains all the belonging group details?

Comment: You can look at the `memberOf` attribute in the results of your search.